# How to fix "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" for geoip2 java running under Hive

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hive, user-defined-functions, geoip2

I am having trouble when executing a UDF with geoip2 (maxmind) as dependency under Hive 2.3.4 (java 8) the same code works fine under older versions of hive that use java 7 and also under Presto that use java 8.

I have tried using exact dependencies (maven) and manual compiling, multiple versions of hive, reducing the code and dependencies to bare minimum

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import com.maxmind.geoip2.record.City;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.model.CityResponse;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.exception.GeoIp2Exception;

public final class CityName extends UDF {
        public String evaluate(String dbFile) throws IOException,GeoIp2Exception {
            File database = new File(dbFile);
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build();
            return "Database: "+dbFile.toString();
        }
}
```

### Error message

```
2019-05-21T16:31:56,631 ERROR [ce3bca33-87aa-4468-b1ed-7080e95efb2d main([])]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(1126)) - FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''/root/GeoIP2-City.mmdb'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String com.example.hive.udf.CityName.evaluate(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException,com.maxmind.geoip2.exception.GeoIp2Exception,java.net.UnknownHostException with arguments {/root/GeoIP2-City.mmdb}:com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.(Lcom/maxmind/geoip2/DatabaseReader$Builder;Lcom/maxmind/geoip2/DatabaseReader$1;)V
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''/root/GeoIP2-City.mmdb'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String com.example.hive.udf.CityName.evaluate(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException,com.maxmind.geoip2.exception.GeoIp2Exception,java.net.UnknownHostException with arguments {/root/GeoIP2-City.mmdb}:com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.(Lcom/maxmind/geoip2/DatabaseReader$Builder;Lcom/maxmind/geoip2/DatabaseReader$1;)V
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.process(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:1367)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultRuleDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRuleDispatcher.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatchAndReturn(DefaultGraphWalker.java:105)
.......
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.(Lcom/maxmind/geoip2/DatabaseReader$Builder;Lcom/maxmind/geoip2/DatabaseReader$1;)V
at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader$Builder.build(DatabaseReader.java:160)
at com.example.hive.udf.CityName.evaluate(CityName.java:20)
... 47 more
```

Answer (score 0):

We hit a very similar issue to that. In our case it turned out in the classpath of the Hive deployment there is an obsolete version of maxmind-db. This might even be by default on newer releases of Hive, but I haven't confirmed yet.

To fix, just shade any references to com.maxmind. Also, just to be safe, shade any any references to fasterxml.jackson as well - that's one of the core dependencies of GeoIP2 and conflicts of that in the classpath tend to cause weird runtime issues like this one. You can see an example of that in a [PR addressing such issue](https://github.com/Spuul/hive-udfs/pull/4/files) in one of the Hive UDF GeoIP libs.